# How can i add textbox in site information

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Alter the following form.
admin/config/system/site-information

1. Add a textbox in the site details section, below the email address textfield. The name of the textbox should be site_organisation.
2. Save the value entered in this textbox in a variable when the save configuration button is clicked.
3. The saved value should be displayed when the page is reloaded.

How can i do that? which module used for that?

Answer (score 0):

Those are forms so you could use hook_form_alter to alter those forms:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Also, check out this article:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1988004